# Odd issue with npm install

Tags: node.js, macos, bash, terminal, npm

So I'll start off by saying that I am on OSX Yosemite preview right now and that could be the cause of my issue. Kind of doubt it but maybe...

I've noticed some odd things when I try to install a packages with npm. Normally, the list of all the packages git location and http status would be printed out, but I'm not getting that.

Whats happening is that I'm getting a `\` that rotates while it tries to retrieve the package and it's dependencies. So while npm is working and I can install things, this odd display error is making me think something somewhere is broken on my laptop.

I am using NVM

- Node Version:0.10.30
- npm Version: 1.4.21
- NVM Version: 0.13.0
- OSX Yosemite
- Iterm

I also have [bash-it](https://github.com/revans/bash-it) install for my bash profile.

To visually see whats going on, I [**made a screencast**](http://youtu.be/QE94aM907O4) of an npm install process.

Any ideas or tips are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Ran npm `sudo npm cache clean` and the issue is still there

Comment: Just curious as too whoever down-voted, any particular reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So some more [research](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5638) shows that this is a config option with npm, not an issue.

To resolve this, you need to change your npm config options

```
$ npm config set spin false
$ npm config set loglevel http
```